# Why div count keeps returning 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a real simple problem that I can't seem to find a real simple answer to. The simple problem is that my jQuery div count keeps returning 0, I have no idea why. I've tried .children(), to no avail. I'm using 1.8.3, so, I believe, size() won't work - I tried anyway, no avail. It should be as straight forward as my code below.

Example of the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="someID">
  <div class="someClass">blah</div>
  <div class="someClass">blah</div>
  <div class="someClass">blah</div>
  <div class="someClass">blah</div>
  <div class="someClass">blah</div>
  <div class="someClass">blah</div>
</div>
```

Example of jQuery:

```
var number = $('#someID > div').length;
alert(number);
```

My alert keeps returning 0 when in fact it should be returning 6. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wrap that in document ready, and you're good to go!

Comment: Works fine for me in jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a conflict somewhere else? Seems to be working in this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/KjwWG/

Answer (score 2):

Are you using this after your page has finished loading? Using a $(document).ready() block :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var number = $('#someID > div').length;
   alert(number);
}
```

To make sure that your items have been loaded. Also you can probably change your selector to :

```
$('#someID div')
```

Comment: This seems to be correct i tried the code using jsfiffle and it alerts 6 http://jsfiddle.net/Mwd2A/11/

Comment: Paul, you are the man! That was indeed the problem. I thought I included that at the top of my js file...apparently not. Thanks again.